# How to add static library .a file in link binary with library in cocoapod

Tags: ios

I made a simple test project but the problem is that i need to drag .a file to the link binary with libraries all the time so is there any other way to create pod spec file so as that i don't need to drag .a file everytime . Any help would be appreciable .

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use [vendored_libraries](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#vendored_libraries) with [public_header_files](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#public_header_files).

For example you can look at [Google](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/8/b/3/Google/3.0.3/Google.podspec.json) podspec.

Comment: hi Andrew i am still unable to get .a file in link binary with library after specifying vendor_library too . I made it like  s.vendored_libraries = 'Libraries/myLibrary-v1.1.a'  in pod specification file is it ok??

Comment: I didn't do it, therefore can't exam your  solution. But Google does it by using framework wrapper around *.a file and headers. (you can see it by the link I've added before).
If you use !use_frameworks in your pod file, read this thread https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3701

Comment: Also you can find example of static library in the podSpec on OpenSSL library https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/e/e/3/OpenSSL/1.0.210/OpenSSL.podspec.json

Comment: Yes i have got the solution i used the same  vendored_libraries.Thank you so much Andrew .